# Selecting input elements whose parent elements are not disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

Whelp, I've been staring at/Googling this for an hour so I figure it's time to ask SO for help.

Basically, I have a plugin that operates on `input` checkboxes, where each one is nested inside a corresponding `label`.  Checking a checkbox is supposed to make something happen, but only if the parent `label` is not disabled.  With my code, it is performing the action for **all** the checkboxes, regardless of whether or not they are supposed to be disabled.

HTML:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary btn-lg bottom-margin-tiny opacity btn-block" >
    <input class="hidden" type="checkbox" name="chapters[]" value="3">
    <i class="fa fa-book"></i> &nbsp;Chapter 3 
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary btn-lg bottom-margin-tiny opacity btn-block" disabled>
    <input class="hidden" type="checkbox" name="chapters[]" value="4">
    <i class="fa fa-book"></i> &nbsp;Chapter 4 
</label>
```

JS:

```
    var pluginDiv = this;   // Defined in my plugin, works fine
    var pluginCheckboxButtons = this.find("input[type='checkbox']").filter(function(){
        return !($(this).parent().prop("disabled"));
    });
    pluginCheckboxButtons.change(function() {
       // Does a thing
    });
```

Comment: I don't think that `<label>` elements have a `disabled` property (certainly not a valid `disabled` attribute).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since disabled is not a default property of `label`, maybe try changing

```
return !($(this).parent().prop("disabled"));
```

to

```
return !$(this).parent().is("[disabled]")
```

Comment: That did it!  Didn't realize that `label` isn't supposed to have the `default` property.  Would it make more sense to make them `button`s rather than `label`s?

Comment: No, unless you move the check-boxes outside of the changed-parent, because interactive elements can't have interactive child elements.

Comment: in HTML5 you can add "data" to any DOM element using an attribute that starts with `data-`. One way would be `<label data-disabled="true" >`. Alternately, you could just add a class `disabled` to the label and say `.is(".disabled")`.

Comment: @Ninsly the problem is that I'd still need to add the `disabled` property so that Bootstrap applies the correct styling :-/  Adding an extra class/attribute makes it a little less elegant.

Comment: I've been looking through [all](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) [their](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) and I can't find where bootstrap supports `disabled` attributes in a label. I may be overlooking it, but it seems like they use classes. Are you sure that adding a `disabled` class and removing the `disabled` attribute doesn't also style it?

Comment: I thought I had tried it and it didn't work.  But, referencing the non-default property is working nicely :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change your JS to this:

```
var pluginDiv = this;   // Defined in my plugin, works fine
var pluginCheckboxButtons = pluginDiv
    .find('input:checkbox') // use :checkbox shorthand
        .filter(function(){
            return ! $(this).parent().is(':disabled');
        });
```